# ubuntu 12.04 Init process provokes memory leak and CPU intensive usage

Tags: 12.04, ram, cpu, init

I have lately been having some memory and CPU issues with init process. After rebooting, the memory used by it keeps increasing at quite high pace, and after half hour it occupies all the memory RAM (4GB). Something similar happens with the usage of CPU.
As a workaround, I kill the process after every reboot (funnily enough, `sudo kill 1` works, whereas `sudo kill -9 1` doesn't). Init process restarts and there is no memory leak or CPU greediness any more. But I'd like to fix the problem properly.
Any suggestions will be more than welcome. 
Thanks